# how to make three column layout like this in css3

Tags: css

So there are 3 columns all with 100% vertical height.

left column has fixed width of 80px.

middle column and right column fill in the available space by ratio of 80% to 20%. So middle takes up 80% space, and right one takes 20% space.

right column width however if is less than 100px that it becomes fixed to 100px. min-width is 100px and max-width is 20% of available space.

I know right now there is no way to refer available vertical or horizontal space, or choose what percentage refers to...and that's why i am lost.

I can't use flexbox, and don't want to use javascript (but be sure it's not possible with css first).

Comment: Where is your codes ?

Comment: yes this question doesn't have quick answer...and code i had written in jsfiddle using display:inline-block...it wasn't able to do what i wanted in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily achieved using `display: table` and `display: table-cell`.

http://jsfiddle.net/Mgzbq/

### HTML

```
<div class="table main">

<div class="cell left">left</div>

<div class="cell">

<div class="table inner">
<div class="cell center"></div>
<div class="cell right"></div>
</div>

</div>

</div>
```

### CSS

```
.table {
    display: table;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;/* Keep this as top|middle|bottom, otherwise the container table of center and right div will have "vertical-align: baseline" and doesn't position properly if there is no content in center and right div*/
}
.left {
    width: 80px;
    background-color: #E07749;
}
.center {
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #E0DD49;
}
.right {
    width: 20%;
    min-width: 100px;
    background-color: #49E0AE;
}
.main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
.inner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: @MuhammadUmer - You said "right one takes 20% space", didn't you?

Comment: yes...but i played with it and even if you don't specify width for one cell in table when there are two cells in a row. Other one fills in the rest by itself. so if one takes 80% then other automatically is taking 20%. can you check.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer yes! you can :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gJips) what you want.

CSS

```
*{
  margin: 0
}
body, html, .outer, .leftCol, .rightSec, .innerCnt{
  height: 100%;
}
.leftCol {
  min-height:100px;
  width: 80px;
  float: left;
  background: red
}
.rightSec {
  margin-left:80px
}
.innerCnt {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.midCol {
  width: 80%;
  background: green;
  height:100px;
  display: table-cell;
}
.rightCol {
  min-width: 100px;
  display: table-cell;
  background: yellow;
  height:100px;
}
```